# Match links in the list with buttons

Tags: javascript

There is a pop-up with a form for selecting the desired denomination of a gift card with a list of denominations, which you poke at, the desired denomination is selected and then you press the button and fly away for payment. There is a list of products with a list with a Buy card button. It is necessary that when you click on a button on a certain product from the list, a window opens where the nominal value is already selected in the form. Since the urls of each product and the nominal selection buttons in the form contain the same lines "nominal-{}", I decided to go through all the urls in the list of products and match them with the buttons.

```
/*всплывающее окно*/
    const popup = document.querySelector('.popup');
    const popupOverlay = document.querySelector('.popup__overlay');
    const popupBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.popup-btn');
    const popupClose = document.querySelector('.popup__close');

    for (const pb of popupBtn) {
        pb.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            document.body.classList.add('popup-open');

           // список того что будем искать
            var fields = [
                'nominal-500',
                'nominal-1000',
                'nominal-1500',
                'nominal-2000',
                'nominal-2500',
                'nominal-3000',
                'nominal-3500',
                'nominal-4000',
                'nominal-5000',
                'nominal-7000',
                'nominal-8500',
                'nominal-10000'
            ];

            var nominals = document.querySelectorAll(`.${fields.join(', .')}`);

            fields.forEach(field => {
                
                const products = document.querySelectorAll('.product a'); //перебираем ссылки
                
                products.forEach(product => {
                    if(product.href.indexOf(field) > -1) { // ищем нужную ссылку
                        nominals.forEach(nominal => {
                            nominal.classList.remove('active-nominal');
                            if (nominal.classList.contains(field) ) {
                                nominal.click();
                                nominal.classList.add('active-nominal');
                            }
                        })
                    }

                })
                
            });
        })
        
    }

    function popClose() {
        document.body.classList.remove('popup-open');
    }

    function popRemove(e) {
        if(e.code === "Escape" && document.body.classList.contains('popup-open') || e.target === popupOverlay || e.target === popupOverlay) {
            popClose();
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener('keydown', popRemove);
    popup.addEventListener('click', popRemove);
    popupClose.addEventListener('click', popClose);
```

The pop-up works as it should. It is not possible only to adequately compare the link to the product in the block of which the button and the buttons for selecting denominations in the form were clicked. If it is salted, it outputs the entire list of urls, not a specific one. What do I need to do?

I add url - https://kartaapple.ru/glavnaya-novaya/. Everything is not in English there. But the code has no boundaries.

Comment: Please create a small snippet with html too.

Comment: I add url - https://kartaapple.ru/glavnaya-novaya/. Everything is not in English there. But the code has no boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added index to the cycle of buttons opening popups and substituted it into my products. So it all turned out